# Avoid Using Volatile Fix

Tags: java, concurrency, sonarqube, volatile, pmd

One of the rule defined in the PMD rule set is: **"Avoid using Volatile"** which explains that **"Use of modifier volatile is not recommended"**. This rule is mentioned under the **Controversial Rule Set** of PMD.
In my team, we have Sonar configured on various modules which indirectly has the rule set from PMD and hence any use of **volatile** pops as a critical warning.

**Question is why are we using volatile?**
The volatile keyword is used for boolean variables to control the state of the external session. This state is accessed across various threads and hence to know if the state is UP or DOWN, it is maintained as a boolean volatile variable, so that visibility is shared across multiple threads.

**My question is how to fix this sonar warning?**
One solution is to remove the rule from the rule set, which is not allowed because: firstly it is not recommended as these rules form the basic guidelines defined from PMD rule set and secondly the SONAR server in my organisation is a central server being used by all the teams. Hence is not allowed.

Another solution is to ignore the sonar warning by use of some annotation, which is again not recommended on basic rule set.

Can anyone suggest how can we fix this sonar warning in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ever thought of using `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: a tool that discourages you from using volatile when you need to cross the memory barriers is not worth using

Comment: @SleimanJneidi according to this http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html "People don't know what they are doing so the shouldn't". IMHO a bad reason.

Comment: I disagree with the statement in the documentation "Use of the keyword 'volatile' is general used to fine tune a Java application". I have *never* used it for this reason.

Comment: This rule is ridiculous - get rid of the warning but keep your code correct. And it makes absolutely no sense to apply these "controversial" rules blindly. Some of them are even conflicting (such as UnnecessaryConstructor and AtLeastOneConstructor). Some don't make sense: why would you want replace every single instance of HashMap by ConcurrentHashMap in non concurrent code? etc...

Comment: Why can't you just mark the issue as a false positive or as a `won't fix` in sonarqube interface ?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: Thanks for the suggestion, I was not aware that every AtomicBoolean is a volatile boolean internally and hence will get the job done. Although there might be a slight overhead because of extra efforts on atomicity but in my case it will not matter as the number of such operations are few.

Comment: @assylias: Your argument is in-fact very valid and I respect your opinion, but sadly I cannot get rid of the rule because of the limitations of my project I mentioned in my question. Contented to know that I have a supporter thinking in the same line though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this rule does not indicate a general problem in the code - `volatile` is a perfectly fine keyword, and there is nothing wrong with it. That's why it's a [controversial rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html#AvoidUsingVolatile).

On the other hand, using it is indeed a bit of an advanced technique that requires you to know what you are doing. Situations exist where you would know that, let's say, the people who will maintain your code will not have sufficient Java knowledge. In such cases, the rule *may* make sense.

To satisfy the rule in your case, use [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not suppress the warning with an annotation?

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidUsingVolatile")
```